# Python 3: Import files of floats and give them unique identifiers for plotting

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, seaborn

I have two files named "Posterior_C.txt" and "Posterior_l.txt", each containing 5000 float entries, that I would like to import and concatenate into a dataframe (for plotting in [seaborn](https://seaborn.pydata.org/examples/many_pairwise_correlations.html)). Each entry belonging to Posterior_C should be given a label C and each entry belonging to Posterior_l should be called l.

How can I import the data and concatenate them, while creating an unique identifier for each. E.g.

```
0.012 Posterior_C
0.0021 Posterior_C
0.2 Posterior_l
0.52 Posterior_l
```

This is what I've got so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

C=np.loadtxt("Posterior_C.txt")
l=np.loadtxt("Posterior_l.txt")
df={C,l}
df=pd.DataFrame(df)

import numpy as np

xc = np.array(["C"])
c=np.repeat(xc, 5000, axis=0)
import numpy as np

xl = np.array(["l"])
l=np.repeat(xl, 5000, axis=0)
```

But a bit stuck now.

*In R i would do *

```
C<-read.table("Posterior_C.txt,header=FALSE)
l<-read.table("Posterior_l.txt,header=FALSE)
df=rbind(C,l)  
df<-as.data.frame(df)
dfID=rbind(rep("C",NROW(C),rep("l",NROW(l))
df$ID<-cbind(df,dfID[,1] )
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
c = pd.read_table("Posterior_C.txt", header=None)
l = pd.read_table("Posterior_l.txt", header=None)
c['ID'] = 'C'
l['ID'] = 'l'
df = pd.concat([c, l], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you that's spot on. What happens if I have 250 files though? might be tricky to make the ID column one by one. Could the ID column take the id of the file name?

Comment: @HCAI This comment is not really what you have asked in your question, this answers what you have asked for. To do it for 250 files you should provide more information about the file structures, the alphabet doesn't have 250 letters, so not easy to guess.